# Unexpected result from "stringWithFormat:"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

What would be the expected result from the following Objective C code?

```
int intValue = 1;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+02d", intValue];
```

I thought the value of string would be "+01", it turns out to be "+1". Somehow "0" in format string "+01" is ignored. Change code to:

```
int intValue = 1;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", intValue];
```

the value of string is now "01". It does generate the leading "0". However, if intValue is negative, as in:

```
int intValue = -1;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", intValue];
```

the value of string becomes "-1", not "-01".

Did I miss anything? Or is this a known issue? What would be the recommended workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the number gives the width of the field including the sign, not the number of digits.

Comment: @Mark Byers, +1 for the comment! You are correct about it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*@Mark Byers* is correct in his comment. Specifying `'0'` pads the significant digits with `'0'` with respect to the sign `'+/-'`. Instead of `'0'` use dot `'.'`  which pads the significant digits with `'0'` *irrespective of the sign*.

```
[... stringWithFormat:@"%+.2d", 1]; // Result is @"+01"
[... stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", -1]; // Result is @"-01"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+0%d", intValue];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-0%d", intValue];
```

Comment: First line will result in `+0-1` when `intValue` is `-1`. The second line will result in `-01` when `intValue` is `1`.

Comment: so you can check with the if condition if the value is less than 0 or greater than 0 simple.

Comment: Alright. The question is not about adding an extra 0 before the number. Its about padding the number with 0, if the actual number less than 2 digits ;-)